# В чем смысл разделения js и css файлов в npm-пакетах с компонентами?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, npm

Разрабатываем **npm** пакет с компонентами для react, чтобы их переиспользовать в других проектах и на этапе создания конфигурации для билда возник данный вопрос.

Если посмотреть на аналоги [semantic ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com/), [bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/), [material ui](https://material-ui.com), то можно заметить разные подходы:

Подход#1:

```
import "package-name/style.min.css" // или же тегом в <head>
import { Button } from "package-name";
```

Подход#2:

```
import { Button } from "package-name";
```

В первом варианте стили и скрипты представляют собой отдельные файлы, которые по факту не работают друг без друга. Во втором случае `Button` является скомпилированным файлом `.js` в котором содержатся и его стили и не нуждается в дополнительной загрузке CSS.

**Есть ли какая то разница между подходами? В чем плюсы минусы каждого из них?**

Спасибо

Comment: Возможно в первом случае разработчик предполагает изменение стилей программистом как ему нравится, но это только гипотеза. Какой-то принципиально разницы нет. Все равно ведь в итоге все это будет собрано в бандлы так, как настроит свой вебпак разраб. Есть разница, если речь идет о сайте в продакшне. Иногда нужно просто изменить стили не изменяя скрипты, чтобы в итоге браузер пользователя взял скрипты из кеша, а стили загрузил по новой, для скорости загрузки.

Comment: @MishaSaidov Я вот не уверен насчет того что "в итоге все это будет собрано в бандлы так, как настроит свой вебпак разраб", потому что мне кажется что вебпак будет собирать по пользовательской конфигурации только в первом случае, во втором стили в js там же и останутся. Не так ли?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Отдельное подключение CSS позволяет заменить файл стилей на другой. К примеру, пользователь bootstrap может сделать вот так и заменить шрифт на всём сайте:

```
$font-family-sans-serif: My Cool Font, $font-family-sans-serif;
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Также подключение CSS в head позволяет стилям загрузиться еще до скриптов - что полезно когда показать контент надо сразу же, а скрипты грузятся долго.

В то же время, второй способ позволяет использовать независимую стилизацию для разных компонентов, при которой одни компоненты гарантированно не будут перекрывать своими стилями стили других компонентов. Смотрите технологии [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/), [Css Modules](https://habr.com/ru/post/335244/) и [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) (Web Components, Shadow Css).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы Вы уточнить насчёт компиляции, есть ли какая то разница в конечном билде?

Comment: Организовал конкурс чтобы получить более исчерпывающий ответ, а получаю всё тоже самое...